# Meaning of "А червоним черевичкам таки дам, таки дам!" in the song "Од села до села"

Tags: значення-слів

[Од села до села](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BC2iFAjA_9Q):

> Ох ви, дітки мої,
>   Мої голуб'ята,
>   Не журіться, подивіться,
>   Як танцює мати.
>   Сама в найми піду,
>   Діток в школу оддам,
>   **А червоним черевичкам
>
>   Таки дам, таки дам!**

What is the meaning of this, especially "таки дам"? I looked up the meanings of **[таки](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)**, but I can't understand the meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likewise in English, common words like *давати* (to give) is widely used in various expressions and idiomatic constructs¹.

This particular song is especially difficult to parse; one may assume that because of the need of fitting the rhyme and the rhythm of the verse, *давати* can be a **truncated idiom**, and we can't tell exactly which one. There are several possibilities, from most general to most specific. All suggest that **the speaker promises to give a hard time to her red boots by dancing hard**.

1. (most general) One of the indirect meanings of *дати* is "punish, penalize":

   > Я тобі дам; Він тобі дасть і т. ін. — [уживається як погроза](http://sum.in.ua/s/davaty).
   >
   > > *— Хто видав так говорити! **Ось я тобі дам!*** (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 319);
2. Also, similar to the above — "to give sb a hard time" (also "punish, penalize, berate"):
   [*дати духу*](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83&table=uk_fraz);
   [*дати перцю*](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2409-daty-perciu.html);
   [*дати жару*](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83&table=uk_fraz):

   > *— Вони селом наваляться на тебе, **дадуть**, скільки влізе, **духу**, а потім відправлять туди, де козам роги правлять* (М. Стельмах).
3. [*дати волю*](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E&table=uk_fraz) — "unleash oneself, set no limit":

   > *Навроцька розсердилась. Вона була нервова й опришкувата, часто **давала волю** словам* (І. Нечуй-Левицький)
4. The most specific expression could be [*дати волю ногам*](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC&table=uk_fraz) — "to dance anxiously":

   > Завзято, запально танцювати.
   >
   > > *На весь голос співали в таборі баяни, змагалися партизанські співаки, **дали волю ногам танцюристи*** (Ю. Збанацький).

---

¹) Idiom stands for a phrase or expression whose meaning can't be inferred from the meanings of individual words it consists from.

Comment: @P.Vovk thanks, I would appreciate if someone edited it. This is not a big mistake, however: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23541/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inanimate_whose

Comment: tnx, I didn't know about that.